# Magento 2 - Use standard product page

Tags: magento2, theme

I am using a Theme for the magento shop. Is it possible to change only the product page to standard and use the Product page top area of the standard magento theme?

I am using a theme baught on themeforest. This theme has a product detail page different then the page of the standard Luma theme. I want to keep the theme as it is and want to use the luma theme for the product detail page.

Comment: please update question in detail what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I am using a theme bought on ThemeForest. 
This theme has a product detail page different than the page of the standard Luma theme.

I want to keep the theme as it is and wants to use the luma theme for the product detail page.

Comment: Please add description in the question with edit not in answer